# Why do I have to add the server SSL certificate if my client program is in Java and not when it is in C#?

Tags: c#, java, .net, ssl, https

If I use `HttpsURLConnection` in a Java program and try to open an URL starting with `https://` I'll get an error message:

> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

and the solution I found is [to add the server certificate to the client certificate storage](http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find). But if I write a C# program that uses `HttpWebRequest` then I don't have to add anything anywhere.

So for me it looks like a C# client "just works" and a Java client only works after being tweaked with a hammer.

Why is an extra step required for a Java client? Can I somehow skip saving the certificate to the client storage of JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpWebRequest will use Window's own certificate store to validate certificates, i.e. the same as IE. If your IE can validate the certificate correctly, either by having the certificate or a CA path back to a trusted root, then HttpWebRequest should accept the certificate OK.

In the Java case I suspect adding the server certificate itself is wrong, unless it's self-signed in which case you'll have no choice. You should add the CA path back to a trusted root instead - you can probably pull these certificates out of Windows's CA store or download them from the root CA's website if you need them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is because C# uses the same HTTP client as MSIE, so it has a lot of pre-installed SSL certificates including one that your use. JVM has less certificates pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Java uses its own set of trust anchors (in the default truststore, see the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)).

If you want to use the Windows certificate store, you can use the [`Windows-ROOT` keystore](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html) as a trust store.

Answer (score 1):

A good source of information on this topic is the [Leveraging Security in the Native Platform Using Java SE 6 Technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html) and [Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) on the Oracle site.

If you want Java to use the Windows certificate store to validate certificates then you can specify the the following system properties on launch:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=Windows-MY -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT`

If you want only one connection to use the Windows certificate store to validate certificates you can modify the following code to fit your needs:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    ks.load(null, null);

    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
    ts.load(null, null);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ts);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory
                .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, new char[0]);

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);    

    URL url = new URL("https://some.web.site.org");
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = 
            (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
    urlConnection.connect();
    try (InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();) {
        byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
        for (int len; (len = in.read(chunk)) > -1;) {
            System.out.write(chunk, 0, len);
        }
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```